# Square brackest cannot be inserted into database

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a textarea that sends its contents to the database. Most of the contents are sent fine like HTML and javascript. I wanted to write some PHP in the following form:

```
   $data = $_POST['stuff'];
```

The above was abbreviated in the database to:

```
 $data = $_POST[
```

I allow for 300 or characters in the database and have tried different database collations like latin1_swedish_ci, utf8_unicode_ci and utf8_bin with no success.

A separate PHP page deals with the insertion

```
INSERT INTO t values ('line_text');
```

The line text varibale grabs contents of the textarea and sends them to the insert statement.

Comment: Please show how you add the information to the database. My guess is you are not using parameterised queries and/or escaping your input properly

Comment: Just one question before that, if I were to use prepared statements would that solve the problem?

Comment: It's likely, yes, assuming that escaping of strings is what is causing the problem. I don't know for definite what's causing the problem without seeing the code. But to be honest you should be using prepared statements and parameters in all situations, as a protection against SQL injection attacks. So whether or not it solves this issue, it's something you need to do anyway

Answer (score 0):

You must escape or "bind" strings before passing them to `INSERT` (and other) statements.

It sounds like you built this; do you see the problem with the apostrophes?

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ( '$data = $_POST['stuff'];' )
```

Comment: Sorry, I have a separate PHP page. I edited my answer to show this.